# Choppy Audio when recording in 16khz mono PCM (WAV) on HTC One

Tags: android, audio, wav, pcm, htc-android

I'm developing an app that requires PCM audio to be recorded 16khz/16bits/mono (1 channel).  It works perfectly on a Motorola ATRIX, but the recording is choppy throughout the file on a HTC One.  I think it is because it is still trying to record in Stereo but writing blanks for the second channel.  If I record in stereo it works great, but I need it in mono.

Has anyone heard of this being an issue?  Mixing the track from stereo to mono is not an option due to time constraints.

```
private static final int        RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 16000;
private static final int        RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int        RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private void startRecording() 
{

    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}
```

Comment: My Application record fine in HTC One at 16KHz, mono . Check this out to test your htc one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.peshal.soundrecorder

Comment: Your app works for me in 16khz mono.  Could you post a sample of your recording code if it is any different from mine so I can see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem, and found an easy solution that works great on both the Atrix and the HTC One.  I don't know WHY it works (any insight on that would be greatly appreciated), but here is what I did.

All I did was change my BufferElements2Rec constant from 1024 to 512.  The constant is used in the code below.  I guess a smaller buffer size allowed it to work properly.

This is my writeAudioDataToFile() function called inside the recording thread:

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile() throws IOException 
{
    //create filename
    filePath = generateFilePath();

    //start writing data
    short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] headerBytes = writeWAVHeader(1);
    os.write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.length);
    while (isRecording)
    {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
        System.out.println("Recording audio to file" + sData.toString());
        try {
            // // writes the data to file from buffer
            byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
            os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```